# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL from Power BI

Tags: postgresql, powerbi

I have downloaded Power BI Desktop in my local machine. When trying to connect to PostgreSQL it is throwing an error.

[image]

For this I have downloaded and installed NpgSQL version 3.2.7 and restarted my machine. Even after that I am unable to connect to PostgreSQL connector.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying SSL certificate for the PostgreSQL server to the machine running Power BI Desktop and import it to Windows certificate store.

Go to the configuration folder for the PostgreSQL server in `postgresql.conf` file, search  for SSL settings, there is one with the location of the SSL certificate.
 Take a look at the server name when you import the SSL certificate and connect from Power BI Desktop using the same server name. 
You can find a similar thread here :[Unable to connect to PostgreSql database using Power BI](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Postgres-error-with-Power-BI-Desktop/td-p/8799)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the **Learn more** option.
2. Navigate to Releases page.
3. Download Npgsql-(version).mis
4. Acknowledge security warnings (if displayed)
5. After that, It will show pop msg "Windows protected your PC", click **more info** option in it & click **run anyway** button.
6. Then do the installation steps.
7. In the **Custom Setup** step, you need to click the drop down **Npgsql GAC Install** and select the **full feature will install on local hard drive** option.
8. After that, you can do other installation steps by clicking next button.
9. Be sure to restart your computer after the installation process is complete.